# Swift get days since in PST issue

Tags: swift, date

I'm trying to get the days since in PST but I'm receiving the following `0001-01-01 07:52:58 +0000` when calling the method. The method is an extension on `Date` and the incoming date is the same format `2022-08-07 08:32:57 +0000`. Not sure where the error is.

```
func daysInPST() -> Int {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "PST")
        let currentDateInPST = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
        let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: currentDateInPST!)
        return days.day!
    }
```

Comment: Haha - So use to using `DateFormatter()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents())` returns Januar 1st in year 1 because all properties are empty (`nil`).

If you want to get the days from `self` to the current date in PST create a custom calendar and set its time zone accordingly

```
extension Date {
    func daysInPST() -> Int {
        var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "PST")!
        return calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: .now).day!
    }
}
```